# Drupal Imagecache: some images show up others don't

Tags: drupal, image-caching

I have a page where I use imagecache to display uploaded images. These images have two imagecache presets, one for thumbnail and the other for large image.
Upon visiting the page, I'm able to see all the thumbnail that image cached creates, although not all of the large images can be previewed. Don't know why...

http://my_site/sites/default/files/image.jpg works!
but
http://my_site/sites/default/files/imagecache/imagecache_subfolder/image.jpg sometimes doesn't work.

Don't really know what's causing the problem. The weird thing is that, when I copy the image from files/ and paste it on files/imagecache/imagecache_subfolder, and set the permission to 777, the image works normally.

I have clean-urls turned on; chmod 0777 sites/*;

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a permission problem, friend.

Either make sure your webserver has write permissions on all sub-folders in /files, or if you are on local webserver just set all folders in files/ to 777 permission.  Be aware that on a public facing webserver all folders would ideally be *owned by webserver* and permissions set to 755.

Comment: I have already set the permissions to 0777 folder/* . New uploaded files have a differente permission though. Don't know if that make any  difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your site status report, is there any errors?

Comment: status reports only shows that I have to update one or two modules for security reasons, nothing that I see could be related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your help guys, I already sort this issue out. For those who might be facing the same kind o problem here is what I did:

1 - Went to content type->display fields, and excluded the second display of my image, which would be the large image.

2 - Change the imagecache preset.

I'm not sure if the solution came with by doing both steps above. Either way, you can try it yourself and see what happens.